# How to align my items on the same line in console?

Tags: c#, arraylist, console

So I'm making a "type in the correct word to the mixed up word" game to practice some c# as I'm pretty new to it. At the end I'd like to output all the words in three columns, but because I'm looping through all my 3 lists one after eachother, the next list it iterates through, will be outputed after the previous list.

Here is the console-output:

[image: The actual output]

Here is my code:

```
String s = String.Format("{0, -10} {1, -10} {2, -10}\n\n","The mixed word: ","The correct word: ", "Your input: ");
index = 0;

while (index < 3)
{
    maxval = 0;

    while (maxval < words.TheList.Count())
    {
        foreach (var value in words.TheList[index])
        {
            if (index == 0)
            {
                s += String.Format("{0, -10}\n", $"{value}");
            }
            else if (index == 1)
            {
                s += String.Format("{0, -10} {1, -10}\n", null, $"{value}");
            }
            else if (index == 2)
            {
                s += String.Format("{0, -10} {1, -10} {2, -10}\n", null, null, $"{value}");
            }
            else if (index > 2)
            {
                break;
            }

            maxval++;
        }
    }

    index++;
}
Console.Write($"{s}");
```

I expect all the three lists to be on the same height/line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the three lists are of the same length, here is a solution:

```
for (int i = 0; i < words.TheList[0].Count; i++)
{
    s += String.Format("{0, -10} {1, -10} {2, -10} \n", words.TheList[0][i], words.TheList[1][i], words.TheList[2][i]);
}
Console.Write($"{s}");
```

Comment: I can't use .Length, because my List contains yet another List<string>.That's what the error-message says.

Comment: What happens when you replace `.Length` with `.Count`.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of printing all the values from one list at a time, print the 'Xth' value from each list on one row.

```
for(var index = 0; index < words.TheList[0].Count; index++)
{
    Console.Write($"{words.TheList[0][index]} {words.TheList[1][index]} {words.TheList[2][index]}");
}
```

Comment: I can't use .Length, because my List contains yet another List<string>.That's what the error-message says.

Comment: " 'List<string>' does not contain a definition for 'Length' and no accessible extension method 'Length' accepting a first argument of type 'List<string>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) "

Comment: Ah yes, that happens a lot. Use `Count` for lists and `Length` for arrays. That's a good example of why your code sample should be complete. Ideally we should be able to copy and paste it into a code editor and test it, otherwise we're just writing code that we hope works!

Comment: Oh ok... Well next time I'll paste the entire code then. Thx again.

Comment: It can be tricky knowing how much to include, people complain if you post too much or too little. Ideally it needs to be minimal and complete to get a good answer.